# How do I pre join data for django web application

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On my iOS app, when a user logs in I start a series of firebase listeners for my users data... Profile, Accounts, Campaigns, etc..

How and where would I do something like this is django/python? I have a firebase db. I configure it in the top of my views.py, I log the user in on my login view. At this point in the iOS app, I add it to an AppState File and can call it from any view. In django, I ended up calling the data and creating my "joins" in the actual view like so:

```
campaign_list = []
results = db.child('campaigns').get(refresh_token)
for campaign in results.each():
    campaign = models.Campaign().db_snapshot(campaign)
    result = db.child('accounts').child(campaign.userUUID).get(refresh_token)
    campaign.account = models.Account().db_snapshot(result)
```

Now I have my campaign object and attached the account object. db is set from the config at the top of my views.py. I believe this the correct way? I know its weird to use firebase and django, and I'm slowly switching to postgresql, but in the mean time, I have to continue to use firebase.

So how do I create a so called snapshot of my user, then access the data when they visit specific views. Aka, create a list of accounts, then on the accounts view, show the list. Instead of creating the list when the user visits the view.

Is this caching? haha

I've read two tutorials on elastic search and that seems like one of the tools I will need. But I also create lists of the data. I.e. I add analytics to the account data. Like a join. Is this possible in elastic search?

The other talked about create_command core. This was interesting and potentially what I need, however, if I placed my listeners in there, it would start on the WebApp startup, but wouldn't know the logged-in users info, so I would have to create every list upfront...? The tutorials that I read on django didn't really go into this a whole lot. And I know Im supposed to keep sessions light.

Any help and links are appreciated!

Denis Angell

Comment: So you're trying to execute the firebase query once when the django server is started and that's it? You don't want it to refresh at any  point?

Comment: Kind of... I can make it a listener and so whatever list or object list I create will update on new information. I just want to grab that instance overtime I open a view/webpage instead of running the query in the view

Comment: Have you tried running the query in the view? Is it too slow? That would be a much simpler option if you can get away with it.

Comment: thats where it is currently. Elastic is what I'm aiming at.